# does sscanf() delete characters from stdin when %*[^|] delimiter used?

Tags: c, stdin, delimiter, scanf

According to the man page for sscanf(), the * character

> An optional '*' assignment-suppression character: scanf() reads input
>   as directed by the conversion specification, but discards the input.

From this, I (rightly?) assume that something like

```
sscanf(string,"%*[^|]%*c%[^|]%*c", vars)
```

Would take the input, "text|neededtext|", ignore all text before the first "|" (ie deleting it from stdin?), ignore (and delete from stdin) the next character, ie the "|" store the "neededtext" and then delete the final "|" character, leaving stdin empty? 
If yes, then is it ever needed to run a cleanup function after this sscanf() call, to catch some weird exception just in case something goes wrong, or is the code above always guaranteed to work?

I have run some tests, and it appears that sscanf() does eat up all characters from stdin, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Your analysis is mostly correct except that you're looking at `sscanf()` which reads from a string, not 'stdin'!  Also, `sscanf()` is strictly non-destructive; it does not alter its input string.  There might be a newline left over.  You should test the return value from `sscanf()` to be sure it got the data (if there wasn't a pipe before, you'd get 0 returned).  You can't directly tell whether the pipe after was matched.

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you! Yes, of course sscanf reads from a string, and the fgets I used would read from the stdin

Comment: Make sure you follow @JonathanLeffler advise and check the return from `sscanf`. The error handling for both `scanf` and `sscanf` is based around the number of input items successfully matched and assigned. Your use of the `*` to discard input allows the input to be skipped without increasing the matched count. If you are not checking the return, you have no way of initially knowing if you actually have what you think you have...

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I am doing,  the input is checked and padded to fit the format, and then the returned value from sscanf is checked as well. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Not always.  See #2

A [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533814/does-sscanf-delete-characters-from-stdin-when-delimiter-used#comment52925748_32533814)  commented, `sscanf()` works with strings and does not affect `stdin`.  Let us assume the question is about the `*scanf()` family instead.

Problems with `*scanf(string,"%*[^|]%*c%[^|]%*c", vars)`

1. Code does not check the result of `*scanf()`.  This leads to subtle to detect problems.  Best to code a check.

   ```
   char vars[100];
   if (sscanf(string,"%*[^|]%*c%99[^|]%*c", vars) != 1) Handle_Error();
   ```
2. `"%*[^|]"` scans nothing and stops the whole scan function if the leading character is `'|'`.   `"%*[^|]"` scans 1 or more  non-`'|'`, not 0 or more.  Hence the "Not always" above.  With `scanf()`, no characters are consume - they remain in `stdin`.
3. The only possible character after `"%*[^|]"` to continue scanning is `'|'`.  Might as well code `"%*[^|]%|"` than `"%*[^|]%*c"`
4. `sscanf()` differs from `scanf()` and `fscanf()` in that the later 2 can scan and save a null character `'\0'`.  `sscanf()` stops scanning upon reaching the null character.  IMO: Use of `"%s"` and `"%[^...]` with `fscanf() scanf()` should be avoided to prevent a hacker exploit.  OP's `fgets()+sscanf()` is the better approach.
5. `%[^|]` lacks a width.  Without this limit, buffer overrun is not prevented.  See #1.
6. `"%*c"` at the end may or may not scan a character.  The result value does not reflect its success or failure as scan directives with `'*'` do not contribute directly to the return value.  If successful trailing scanning of `"%*c"` was needed (which could be `"|"` per point #3), suggest using `"%n"` to detect is scanning proceed that far.

   ```
   char vars[100];
   int n = 0;
   sscanf(string,"%*[^|]|%99[^|]| %n", vars);
   if (n > 0) Success();

   // May also want to use
   if (string[n]) Fail_ExtraTextOnLine();
   ```
7. In C, `%*[^|]` is a `scanf` *specifier*, not delimiter.